# How to make CSS fade out but the HTML to collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element, which has its css style controlled by javascript, simply by adding/removing classes.

For example, I have a hide class, which I apply to an element when I want it to hide, and when the element is hidden the page restructures as if the content was never there (collapse). This is great.

I now want the item to fade out first, and then collapse but I'm lost.

My effort is

```js
 document.getElementById("clicky").addEventListener("click", changeMe);

function changeMe() {
 var ele = document.getElementById("item");   
    ele.className= "hide";
}
```

```css
#clicky{cursor:pointer;}

.hide { 
 
    animation: fadeout 1s ;
 -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s ; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
 }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;}
    to {
 display:none;
 visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;}
 
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;}
    to {
 display:none;
 visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<a id="clicky">Click me</a>
<br /><br />

<div>I remaine!</div>
<div id="item">I should go bye byes but also collapse so the page can re-organise when I disapear!!!!!</div>
<div>I should stay forever but move physically up the page when the line above disappears!</div>
```

Comment: Set `height: 0;`? Would that not work?

Comment: @Ruddy, no, sadly it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You have an explicit time for your animation, so you could say something like `setTimeout(function() { ele.style.display = 'none'; }, 1000);`

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Sure about that? [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/2bb0a2fe988193a1fbdd4fe6a93a8136) *This demo is using Autoprefixer*.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Fadeout and slidup are standardized functions in jQuery and easier in use. Also, you can wait for animations to finish and then continue with a different animation.

Comment: Yes @Ruddy, I'm sure. You've got the fade, but not the collapse!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just animate values of `max-height` in `fadeout`, e.g.

```
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
        max-height: 999px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        max-height: 0;
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcy9yz4j/).

Comment: I don't have so much knowledge about css, but it is better if it can be done like that +1

Comment: This does not exactly what OP asks, but I am nitpicking here :). It executes opacity and height simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple you could use `max-height:0px`. By using this your height will be set to 0 and it will look like that the element never exists.

```
document.getElementById("clicky").addEventListener("click", changeMe);

function changeMe() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("item");   
    ele.className= "hide";
    setTimeout(function() { ele.style["max-height"] = '0px'; }, 1000);
}
```

JSFIddle:http://jsfiddle.net/p8430eph/

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with the height, I would just set the `display` to `none` after the animation is finished.

```js
 document.getElementById("clicky").addEventListener("click", changeMe);

function changeMe() {
 var ele = document.getElementById("item");   
    ele.className= "hide";
    setTimeout(function() {
        ele.style.display = 'none';
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#clicky{cursor:pointer;}

.hide { 
 
    animation: fadeout 1s ;
 -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s ; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
 }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;}
    to {
 display:none;
 visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;}
 
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;}
    to {
 display:none;
 visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<a id="clicky">Click me</a>
<br /><br />

<div>I remaine!</div>
<div id="item">I should go bye byes but also collapse so the page can re-organise when I disapear!!!!!</div>
<div>I should stay forever but move physically up the page when the line above disappears!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout() and give it another css class :)

```js
document.getElementById("clicky").addEventListener("click", changeMe);

function changeMe() {
 var ele = document.getElementById("item");   
    ele.className= "hide";
    setTimeout(function(){
        ele.className = "disable";
    },1000);
}
```

```css
#clicky{cursor:pointer;}

.disable{
  display: none !important;
  }
.hide { 
 
    animation: fadeout 1s ;
 -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s ; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
 }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;}
    to {
 display:none;
 visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;}
 
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;}
    to {
 display:none;
 visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<a id="clicky">Click me</a>
<br /><br />

<div>I remaine!</div>
<div id="item">I should go bye byes but also collapse so the page can re-organise when I disapear!!!!!</div>
<div>I should stay forever but move physically up the page when the line above disappears!</div>
```